# two models in one action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I get the feeling I am violating MVC best practise here, but I don't see how.

I have a form with two buttons with different names so when it gets posted to the action, I can do different things based on which button is pressed.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Display", "PlayBoard")
// form properties
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Display">Filter PlayBoard</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Report">Report View</button>
```

then in the controller:

```
[HttpPost, FlexAuthorize]
public ActionResult Display(FormInput filter )
{
    if (Request["Report"] != null)
    {  
          var model = queryRepository.Load<FormInput , ReportViewPlayBoardView>(filter);
          return View(model);
    }
    if (Request["Display"] != null)
    {
        var model = queryRepository.Load<FormInput , DisplayPlayBoardView>(filter);
        return View(model);
    }
```

When I click the report button, it runs through the query ok but then comes back with the exception: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '...ReportViewPlayBoardView', but this dictionary requires a model item of type '...DisplayPlayBoardView'."

I don't really follow why this has to be a DisplayBoardView model that gets returned.

edit: fixed it, I just had to change the view command on the report branch to: return View("ReportView", model);

Comment: what is the purpose of forminput in load method?

Answer (score 1):

fixed it, I just had to change the view command on the report branch to:

```
 return View("ReportView", model);
```